# React component not refreshing when redux state has been updated with successful action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

New to React/Redux combo and trying to work through an issue.

When a user first visits or logs in / a fetch_user api request is made. The intention is that the page would display differently based on their login status. In redux dev tools I can see the state being updated and fields being populated to 'auth' after the initial state, however, while I am in a subcomponent of the app the value is seen as undefined. Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in advance.

```
    // app.js
            const initialState = {};
    const history = createHistory();
    const store = configureStore(initialState, history);

    const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('app');

    const render = messages => {
      ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
              <App />
            </ConnectedRouter>
          </LanguageProvider>
        </Provider>,
        MOUNT_NODE,
      );
    };

    // index.js
            class App extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        console.log('here');
        this.props.fetchUser();
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <ThemeWrapper>
            <AppContext.Consumer>
          ..... 
        App.propTypes = {
            fetchUser: PropTypes.any.isRequired
        };

   export default withRouter(connect(null, actions)(App));


  import { FETCH_USER } from '../actions/types';

  export default function (state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_USER:
        console.log('1');
        return action.payload || false;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
    // actions
    export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/current_user');
      // res is the output of the axios request
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
    };

// Banner.js - auth = undefined
render() {
    console.log(this.props);
// === auth = undefined. I may be accessing it incorrectly


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    gradient: state.getIn([reducerUI, 'gradient']),
    chat: state.getIn([chatUI, 'chatSelected']),
    auth: state.auth
  });

  const BannerMaped = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
  )(Banner);

  // configure store

      export default function configureStore(initialState = {}, history) {
        // Create the store with two middlewares
        // 1. sagaMiddleware: Makes redux-sagas work
        // 2. routerMiddleware: Syncs the location/URL path to the state
        const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history), reduxThunk];

        const enhancers = [applyMiddleware(...middlewares)];

        // If Redux DevTools Extension is installed use it, otherwise use Redux compose
        /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle, indent */
        const composeEnhancers =
          process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
          typeof window === 'object' &&
          window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
            ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
                // TODO Try to remove when `react-router-redux` is out of beta, LOCATION_CHANGE should not be fired more than once after hot reloading
                // Prevent recomputing reducers for `replaceReducer`
                shouldHotReload: false,
              })
            : compose;
        /* eslint-enable */
        const store = createStore(
          createReducer(),
          fromJS(initialState),
          composeEnhancers(...enhancers),
        );

        // Extensions
        store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
        store.injectedReducers = {}; // Reducer registry
        store.injectedSagas = {}; // Saga registry

        // Make reducers hot reloadable, see http://mxs.is/googmo
        if (module.hot) {
          module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
            store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.injectedReducers));
          });
        }

        return store;
      }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing everything correctly just not accessing the state object appropriately. Stared at this one a little too long.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
gradient: state.getIn([reducerUI, 'gradient']),
chat: state.getIn([chatUI, 'chatSelected']),
auth: state.getIn(['auth'])
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Redux store updates are mapped to individual components and not the whole app.

This line means, only the `Banner` component will be re-rendered when the store is updated and not your entire app.

```
const BannerMaped = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(Banner);
```

So wherever your `Banner` component is, every time `fetchUser()` response succeeds and updates the store, only your `Banner` component will be re-rendered. If you need to re-render other components, they should also subscribe to store with corresponding `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response. I do understand that. I suppose my concern is that I may be trying to access 'auth' incorrectly. It is undefined in any combination I try to access it. I have been staring at this for a little while now and may be missing something simple.

Comment: I am trying to display different buttons in the banner based off what auth equals

Comment: Can you add the code where you are trying to access `auth` prop? @JohnZ

Comment: // Banner - auth = undefined
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    gradient: state.getIn([reducerUI, 'gradient']),
    chat: state.getIn([chatUI, 'chatSelected']),
    auth: state.auth
  });

  const BannerMaped = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
  )(Banner); - Posted above - I am just console logging this.props and I see Object
auth: undefined
chat: 0.. etc. Thank you

Comment: Add the code for `Banner` component. It might help.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? The post below? Any information would be greatly appreciated. I appreciate your time.

Comment: `console.log(this.props);` in `Banner` component, does it execute only once or more than once?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184576/discussion-between-john-z-and-dinesh-pandiyan).

Comment: It only executes once. 
authReducer.js?4dba:17 CASE_FETCH_USER RUNNING
Banner.js?66d0:63 {classes: {…}, gradient: true, chat: 0, auth: undefined, dispatch: ƒ, …}

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pass dispatch actions in connect method. In your case, you have already make fetchUser() action. So, you can pass it in your connect method like this:

```
const BannerMaped = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  fetchUser
)(Banner);
```

I think this will help.

Comment: Interesting. So I have fetchUser run from my index.js - and ending with export default withRouter(connect(null, actions)(App)); Would I go through the efforts of loading all of the actions aka fetchUser? I am confused